# at&t assembly code ebp register undefined behavior

Tags: assembly, gdb, att

Since starting to learn at&t assembly about a month ago I was taught that the %ebp register starting at %ebp-4 and going down (ex. -8/-12) were the local variables. Now that I am getting deeper into assembly though I am noticing calls to %ebp-10 and other non multiples of 4. I am wondering how this works and what the significance of this is.

```
0x08048e2b <+6>:    lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax

0x08048e2b <+6>:    lea    -0x10(%ebp),%eax
```

Above are two examples from disassembling a program I am working on now using gdb. How is this data used correctly if, as I am deducing, it is only half way through the variable or supposed data. Wouldn't %ebp-8 or %ebp-12 be the correct version instead of %ebp-10?

I feel like there is probably an intuitive answer to this question, but I'm just not seeing it and haven't been able to find any resources online about it.

Comment: Note that there is nothing special about `ebp`, the only reason this works in some code is because it's set up by the function prologue to store the stack pointer (the well-known `push %ebp; mov %esp, %ebp` sequence). This is not mandatory, you can use `ebp` as a general purpose register. In fact recent `gcc` versions do that by default when optimizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0x10` *is* a multiple of four. It's a hexadecimal number equal to 16 in decimal which, last I looked into the matter, was equal to `4x4`. I'm old but I'm pretty sure maths hasn't changed *that* much since I went to school :-)

In any case, things on the stack aren't *required* to be aligned on a four-byte boundary. Alignment may speed up certain operations, but:

- it isn't a mandatory thing on the x86 platforms (on *some* platforms, accessing misaligned data causes a fault to be raised); and
- alignment tends to match the argument size (such as a two-byte value "needing" two-byte alignment).

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. The code started blurring together and I wasn't thinking of the 0x10 as a hex value for some reason. My brain just wanted it to be %ebp-10 not %ebp-16 as it really is. Thanks for the clear answer!